# Form Creation and Validation in Android

Tags: android

I'm currently exploring the new features of Android 3.0 and 4.0 and the ActionBar looks good and so does the menu.xml system for making navigation easier and far more consistent (using less code) than before throughout applications.

The same goes for the preferences in Android which have been part of the framework for a long time. It's very easy to create app settings via XML.

Is there a consistent way of creating and validating form data in Android? Its been solved a million times with Java web frameworks of course, but I can't seem to find a straightforward way of doing this without implementing it in my own code.

I've found the EditText.setError() which looks pretty useful, but you are still in charge of setting this yourself in your code and its only available on EditText. It would be cool if there was a corner of the framework that handled all this stuff for you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of EditText based validation (I have not used or tested other form style components with validation) I found that using the setError() method on the EditText component has been adequate.

But other form components exist which developers might want to use of course such as radio buttons, check boxes, spinners etc and these have not been covered with the same sort of validation.

As a side note, I have come across a github project which has extended the setError functionality to provide in-built validation algorithms: [Android Form EditText](https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

For preferences you can use OnPreferenceChangeListener which allows you to trap invalid entries as they are entered.

in your fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Your_Pref = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("Your_Pref");

        Your_Pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Boolean rtnval = true;
                if (Your_Test) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Invalid Input");
                    builder.setMessage("Something's gone wrong...");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.show();
                    rtnval = false;
                }
                return rtnval;
            }
        });
    }
```